# Маракуйя. Как лучше употребить: в ед. или во множ. числе?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

«Его комната оплетена маракуйями» (растение, без плодов).
Склоняюсь к единственному числу – *маракуйей*.

Comment: Ну так если несколько растений, то множественное. Вопрос на пустом месте.

Comment: одно растение...

Comment: Ну как тогда может быть множественное?

Comment: К чему этот спор?

Comment: Где спор? Просто проблема на ровном месте.

Comment: FlossyU, странно, что Вы поменяли принятый ответ. При чем здесь ягоды, прочие плоды и лианы? Ведь Вы сами пишете о растении без плодов. А растение так и называется – маракуйя (есть разные виды).

Comment: Мне понравился вариант.

Comment: Тогда так бы и спрашивали, как лучше написать. А у Вас вопрос: *Есть множественное число?*

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец не обижайтесь, поддержу ваш ответ, он правда у вас правильный в рамках норм современной грамматики, хоть и звучит это всё ужасно коряво при прочтении вслух.

Comment: @Буратино, Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ягоды часто не имеют различия количественной формы для единственного числа и множественного: малина, клюква, морошка, и даже, вишня, слива... Маракуйя очевидно ягода, хотя её называют фруктом, но фрукт - это съедобный плод и его нет в русской биологический классификации. Многосемянные плоды же делятся на: ягоду, яблоко, тыквину и гесперидий(цитрусовые). Маракуйя растет на лиане, как и виноград.

А отвечая на вопрос:

*Комната оплетена лианами маракуйи,* - по аналогии с "лозами винограда", а не "виноградами".

Comment: На самом деле спорный вопрос, так как множественная форма "винограды" существует, в том числе у классиков, хотя в жизни я ни разу не слышал подобной формы слова. Но с виноградами всё-таки звучание более благозвучное, а с маракуйями язык сломаешь посередине, какой-то финский диалект получится.

Comment: Для слуха все же единственное число кажется верным... папайи, питахайи туда же...

Comment: "Маракуйи" звучит гораздо лучше, чем "винограды". "Виноград" — это собирательное. Если несколько растений, то "кусты винограда".

Answer (score 6):

Множественное число слова *маракуйя*, конечно, есть (см. [**1**](https://sklonili.ru/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%8F), [**2**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%8F)). И если бы в комнате росло несколько таких растений одного или разных видов, относящихся к роду [Страстоцвет](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82), то вполне можно было бы написать "оплетена маракуйями".
Но в комментарии Вы пишете, что растение одно. Следовательно, нужно использовать единственное число.

**После изменения вопроса ответ выглядит так:**

Если одно растение оплетает комнату – единственное число.
Если два или больше – множественное.